# How to fix Undefined variable: request in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am going to filter data with districtname in my vehicles table like this,

```
public function index()
    {
       $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
                ->when($request->district, function ($query, $request) {
                    return $query->where('districtname', $request->district);
                })->get();

        return view('vehicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }
```

and my vehicle table like this,

```
id  districtname  vehiclename 
1    alabama          toyota
2    alamaba          ford
3    miyuri           bmw
4    misisipi         benz
5    miyuri           ford
6    alabama          toyota
```

and routes is like this,

```
Route::get('district', [
    'uses' => 'VehicleController@index',
    'as'   => 'districts.index',

]);
```

but got following error msg,

```
Undefined variable: request
in VehicleController.php line 39
```

how can fix this???

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: The `$request` variable is not visible inside the index method, you don't pass an argument with that name.

Comment: then got **Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController::index()** err msg

Comment: You must be pass param in `public function index(Request $request) {}`. Be remember to add `Request` namespace [check](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: did public function index(Request $request) {} but got **Trying to get property of non-object**

Answer (score 1):

When you call **when()** on the query builder, the first argument is the value you want to pass to the callback, that is passed as the second argument.

When you do

```
->when($request->district, function ($query, $request) {
  return $query->where('districtname', $request->district);
})
```

then **$request->district** is passed to the callback, provided it has a value, therefore there is no need to try to access its **district** property.

To fix that, change the above to:

```
->when($request->district, function ($query, $district) {
  return $query->where('districtname', $district);
})
```

Comment: Which model do you want to filter by district name? Vehicles? Uploads?

Comment: Could you dump $request->district and make sure it contains correct value?

Comment: I need filter districtname from vehicles table. and I did dd($request->district); it is printing district name...

Comment: Could you replace ->get() with ->toSql() and ->getBindings() and paste the results here? This will get us the query that is being run

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Undefined variable: request
in VehicleController.php line 39
```

Is because of not using REQUEST in the function index

You will have to use Illuminate\Http\Request in your class as well as you will need to pass the REQUEST obj in your index function.

Check the below code to use it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
                ->when($request->district, function ($query, $district) {
                    return $query->where('districtname', $district);
                })->get();

        return view('vehicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }

}
```